# Get data from a custom field in Azure Devops

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to fetch data from a custom field in all the tasks linked to a particular User Story in Azure DevOps? How can it be done?

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 2):

Linking data from a custom field to a specified work item is not feasible.You can add links to the task items in the Related Work field of the userstory item.